# iTunes store - iPhone App ... customizable background?

Tags: iphone, itunes

At iTunes, some iPhone Applications have their own background image screens.. like Sim City

I'm not talking about "primary screenshot / additional screenshots" or "Large 512x512 icon"

I'm talking about the big eye-candy title screen that some famous iPhone App got inside the iTunes Store screen.. like "Let's GOLF" .. "Sim City" etc.

How to do the same for my own iPhone App? :) Many thanks for reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Apple only lets select developers have custom pages.